# An error in SQL procedure parameters of type varchar

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am a beginner trying to create a procedure that returns the available number of beds in a quarantine center unit.

- UID refers to the Unit ID (4 characters),
- and CID refers to the Center ID (6 characters).

```
create procedure getAvailableBeds(@UID varchar(4), @CID varchar(6), @emptyBeds int output)
as
begin
    declare @bedNum int, @patientNum int

    select @bedNum = NoOfBeds, @patientNum = NoOfPatients
    from Unit
    where @UID = UID and @CID = CID

    @emptyBeds = @bedNum – @patientNum
End
```

The error;

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@UID varchar(4), @CID varchar(6), @emptyBeds int output)
> as
> begin
> declare...' at line 1

I can't seem to figure out the error in my code and I would like some help.

Comment: `@emptyBeds = @bedNum – patientNum` missing `@` for patientNum

Comment: Thanks @Stu but it still doesn't correspond to the error message.

Comment: Don't you need to do `set @emptyBeds = ...`? AFAICT, assigning to a variable without `set` is deprecated and need not work, and it's probably ambiguous here that you want that, without `set`. Semicolons could help too...

Comment: Yup that's one as well @underscore_d. It looks like there's some minor synatx errors here and there:). But,  I,m still stuck with the error shown in the message, line 1. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `@name` is user-defined variable. It cannot be used as procedure parameter.

Comment: PS. Don't try to come up with a new syntax for the server - it still won't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE getAvailableBeds (IN  UID VARCHAR(4), 
                                   IN  CID VARCHAR(6), 
                                   OUT emptyBeds INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT unit.NoOfBeds - unit.NoOfPatients 
    INTO emptyBeds 
    FROM unit
    WHERE UID = unit.UID 
      AND CID = unit.CID;
END
```